# Get list of items from a lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm using the following to get a list of class properties and values. Which works just fine until one of those properties is a generic list.

```
string table = HelperMethods.Class2Table(model, "Details", x => x.Facility, x => x.ServiceType, x => x.PatientName);

public static string Class2Table<T>(T obj, string title, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] props)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  
    sb.Append("<table>");
    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
        sb.Append(GetNameAttribute(prop));
        sb.Append("</td>");
        sb.Append("<td>");
        sb.Append(prop.Compile()(obj));
        sb.Append("</td>");
        sb.Append("</tr>\n");
        sb.Append("<br />");
    }
    sb.Append("</table>");
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

how can I get `prop.Compile()(obj)` to return a comma delimited string when it's a list?

Comment: If it is a list, you should check out [string.Join(..)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue can be solved as easy as using `as` operator to try to cast what the delegate returns to `IEnumerable<object>` and if it's already an `IEnumerable<object>`, use [`string.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx):

> `Join<T>(String, IEnumerable<T>)` is a convenience method that lets you
>   concatenate each member of an `IEnumerable<T>` collection without first
>   converting them to strings. The string representation of each object
>   in the `IEnumerable<T>` collection is derived by calling that object's
>   ToString method.

```
object propertyValue = prop.Compile()(obj);
IEnumerable<object> enumerableValue = propertyValue as IEnumerable<object>;

if(enumerableValue != null) 
{
     propertyValue = string.Join(",", enumerableValue);
}

sb.Append(propertyValue);
```